# Can I change the headers in a MultipartBody part?

Tags: okhttp

I'm trying to send a MultipartBody payload with OkHttp3.
Here's a MWE for creating the payload (plus getting it as a String):

```java
MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json");
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
    .setType(MultipartBody.MIXED)
    .addPart(RequestBody.create(JSON, "{\"foo\": true, \"bar\": \"some string\"}"))
    .build();

Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
requestBody.writeTo(buffer);
String requestBodyAsString = buffer.readUtf8();
```

That automatically adds headers and the result is this:

```
--8d863b3b-72a0-4b29-b4f4-5cc0b68d8117
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 35

{"foo": true, "bar": "some string"}
--8d863b3b-72a0-4b29-b4f4-5cc0b68d8117
```

The server I am sending against requires that the character encoding and Content-Length header are removed as in the following:

```
--8d863b3b-72a0-4b29-b4f4-5cc0b68d8117
Content-Type: application/json

{"foo": true, "bar": "some string"}
--8d863b3b-72a0-4b29-b4f4-5cc0b68d8117
```

The `MultipartBody.Builder()` has `.addPart(Headers headers, RequestBody body)` but I cannot use that to remove headers or override the Content-Type header. Is there a way to change these via the OkHttp API or would I have to edit the payload string directly?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my hacked solution, directly modifying the payload with an interceptor. Note that it's important to adjust the Content-Length header of the overall request as well.

```java
public class MultipartHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {


    @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        String requestBody = requestBodyToString(originalRequest.body());
        String modified = stripHeadersFromMultipart(requestBody);
        Request targetRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain"), modified))
                .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(modified.length()))
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(targetRequest);
    }

    private String stripHeadersFromMultipart(String requestBody) {
        String regexToStrip = "; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: \\d*";
        return requestBody.replaceAll(regexToStrip, "");
    }


    private String requestBodyToString(RequestBody body) {
        String bodyAsString = "";
        try (Buffer buffer = new Buffer()) {
            if (body != null) {
                body.writeTo(buffer);
                bodyAsString = buffer.readUtf8();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info(e);
        }
        return bodyAsString;
    }
}
```

Would be nice to have a less hacky solution though.